# What is the best way to work with big blobs in git?

Tags: git

I have recently read the article about git internals. It turns out that git locally stores copies of blobs (until they are packed). It leads me to the thought that storing big binary data is not the best way in git. How can I work effectively with big blobs?

Just to clarify, let's we have project, where all dependencies (including dependant libs, assets, deploy scripts, etc) are stored in compressed archive (like .rar). That file represents big blob mentioned above. What is the best way to work with it? One of the solutions I found is to move this blob to another git repository. Or am I inventing bicycle?

Comment: Kind of related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58535593/can-git-store-file-containers-as-trees-and-blobs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001663/can-git-treat-zip-files-as-directories-and-files-inside-the-zip-as-blobs .

Comment: https://git-lfs.github.com/ [tag:git-lfs]